# Add element to mobile camera via JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have access to mobile camera from my web app. It works fine but the problem is when I want to push some div / overlay to camera view (it can be PNG image). User who will use it have to see some overlay on his camera view becauase the images have to be taken with a specific way.

The overlay will look like squere with empty space inside what will be look like person.

Is it solution for that?

Comment: yes - HTML with some clever CSS will allow you to do that

Comment: Have you some example? on mobile phone the script turns on the mobile camera - not iframe in browser.

Comment: I can't give you an example because I can't see how you're displaying the camera image

Comment: I need only the code which give me the access to push some image / div to mobile camera.

Comment: sure ... `<img src="url of image"/>` or `<div>your content goes here</div>` - hope that helps - unfortunately I don't know what CSS to add to those to make it work with your HTML, since your HTML is non-existent